# Chrome extension run before page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a idea for a chrome extension that does "kill switch" the connection to the specified domains before connection established. The core idea of this is that I use PAC proxy on Chrome to assign proxies to domains, while browsing, I don't want to access to, let's say facebook.com, with the real IP address, but only with the proxy IP, but in the case the PAC script didn't work, I want to have a backup. So, I need to run the extension script before the load, not on document_start. Possible? (if it's not possible I want to try other way around like using OS level firewall or something, it should be worked. but prefer Chrome level since while I don't want to access to facebook.com on chrome profile A with the bare IP, I may want to access to facebook.com on chrome profile B with the bare IP.)

Comment: Use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest or chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigation in the background script.

Comment: thanks. sounds nice. it meant onBeforeNavigation is onBeforeNavigate?

Comment: I wrote from memory so refer to the documentation for the exact spelling.